# Pull the navigation drawer from the side in code

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, navigation-drawer

I am looking for a way that way that in a certain interception I should be able pull the navigation drawer from the side in code.

Comment: do you mean a MasterDetailPage in Xamarin Forms?

Comment: @Jason Yes I am trying to have it done in code without pulling it from the side

Comment: You mean to open/close the drawer or make navigation ?

Comment: @FabriBertani open/close

Comment: I usually do it by putting this inside a method and then calling that method: `if (Application.Current.MainPage is NavigationPage navigationPage && navigationPage.CurrentPage is MasterDetailPage nestedMasterDetail)
                nestedMasterDetail.IsPresented = !nestedMasterDetail.IsPresented;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MasterDetailPage` has an [IsPresented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.masterdetailpage.ispresented?view=xamarin-forms) property that controls whether or not the master is visible

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether or not the visual element
> that is represented by the Master property is presented to the user.